# Show polymorphic association in form dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a collection of Run objects in a dropdown form. I want to pass Run.id as the value, and display Run.rider.name as the option.

the form

```
<%= form_for p do |f| %>
    <%=f.collection_select :run_id, active_runs, :id, <rider name> %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The classes

```
class Run < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :rider
end


class Rider < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :runs
end
```

What can I pass for `<rider name>` to display the name of the rider the run belongs to?

Comment: Try this, <%= select_tag "run_ids[]", options_from_collection_for_select(active_runs,"id","name") %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)

```
<%= f.select :run_id, options_for_select(active_runs.collect{|run| [run.id, run.name]})  %>
```

Comment: Worked, but select takes `[text, value]`. The opposite of collection_select